# AWS springboot application endpoints not accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-application-load-balancer, onpremises-gateway

Our organisation uses AWS VPC, I have successfully deployed a springboot application into AWS ECS, it’s started fine as per logs, I have also configured Application load balancer ALB for the application instance. When tried to hit application end point through AlB uri from on-premise, the request doesn’t get through. Do I need to setup VPC configuration too?

Comment: Theres not enough info to give you an answer, and the issue sounds like it could be infra not code so this may not be the best site to ask this question.  Yes you need to configure VPC, ALB, Target groups, security groups etc. There are several examples in the docs - eg https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/create-application-load-balancer.html as a starting point. Update your question to be more specific. What is the exact error you receive, can you access the endpoint from an instance within the VPC etc?